# Angular WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?

Tags: angular, warnings

I keep getting these Warnings while deploying:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js
4996:15-36 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/main.ts

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js
5008:15-102 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/main.ts
```

What I've tried:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20357

My project structure:

[image]

My webpack.config.js:

```js
var path = require('path');
plugins: [
  new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)esm5/, path.join(__dirname, './src')),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './src/index.html',
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: 'body'
  }),
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    // global app config object
    config: JSON.stringify({
      apiUrl: 'http://localhost:4000'
    })
  })
],
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `[...]esm5/` to `[...]fesm5/` in the `webpack.config.js` posted above?

Comment: This works, if you post this as an answer, I'll accept it. Can you also explain why this works while the former does not?

Comment: Misspoke, I encountered this in angular 7, webpack is no longer directly configured. Meant to say encountered this, but didn't have a way to configure it. however as a side note, the supported way in ng 8 is to use `ngx-build-plus` npm module to override/extend the base webpack config.

Answer (score 3):

You were on the right direction, except the pluging name, try to add the following to your webpack.config.js after the existing ContextReplacementPlugin

```
new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)fesm5/, path.join(__dirname, './src')),
```

Comment: @FlavorScape this is unfortunate, however, the initial question was about webpack as well as my answer

Answer (score 1):

Same warning message when i update my angular app from 6 to 7.

I remove the message by adding the path `"@angular/": ["../node_modules/@angular/"]` in compilerOptions in the tsconfig.json,

But I'm not sure this is the best solution.

Comment: Could you tell us where with example 
you mean like this 
 "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"@angular/": ["../node_modules/@angular/"]
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }

Comment: like that --> "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
 ...
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["app/*"],
      "@env/*": ["environments/*"],
   ...
      "@angular/*": ["../node_modules/@angular/*"]
    }
  }

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the material using

```
ng add @angular/material
```